# dispatch once issue in ios7 mrc

Tags: objective-c, ios7

In the iOS7 SDK and while using MRC, the following piece of code does not return the shared instance. On runtime it just hangs and it does not move in to the next line of code.

```
+(id)getInstance
{
  static dispatch_once_t pred;
  static IAPManager *inAppManager = nil;
  dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
    inAppManager = [[IAPManager alloc] init];
  });
  return inAppManager;
}
```

What is the reason for this anomaly? This is how I am calling

```
IAPManager *iapManager = [IAPManager getInstance];

if ([iapManager canMakePurchases]) {
    [iapManager loadStore:proUpgradeProductId];
}else{
    UIAlertView *aView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" message:@"This device is not able or allowed to make payments" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [aView show];
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that your call to `IAPManager init` ends up calling `getInstance`? That would cause the issue you describe.

Comment: it could be. Since I have not explicitly called upon init to return the iAPManager self.. this would be calling the init in NSObject. But anyways how can I overcome this issue. :(

Comment: Edit your post to include the definition of `-[IAPManager init]`.

Comment: @robmayoff this is a custom class

Comment: If you put an `NSLog(@"%@", iapManager);` under `IAPManager *iapManager = [IAPManager getInstance];` does it get logged or does it hang before you get there? If so please can you post your init method if you have a custom one.

Comment: Does `IAPManager` have an `init` method?  If so, post the code.

Answer (score -1):

The original getInstance method is absolutely fine (I would declare it as returning IAPManager*, but it doesn't make any difference to how it works). "static" variables are initialised *once* wherever they are.

The problem is most likely that getInstance is called from [[IAPManager alloc] init]. Calling dispatch_once from inside the dispatch_once is an instant deadlock. To find out, you just set a breakpoint in getInstance on the dispatch_once statement. It should be hit once during the first call, and then probably again, and the original call will be on the stack. Or just wait until it hangs, then check in the debugger where each thread is. You'll find a thread waiting for dispatch_once to finish.

Alternatively, it is possible that the init method just doesn't return. Maybe it does some network access that doesn't finish. To step into the code, set a breakpoint on the first (and only) line of the block, that is the [[IAPManager alloc] init] line. Once that breakpoint is reached, you can step through the code.

Comment: You must read the thread carefully and then down vote answers willy-nilly! there is no `init` method defined inside the `IAPManager` therefore no deadlock could happen as you described!

Comment: Can't believe you have criticized and downvoted other users answers and your doesn't even help with the problem. `"There has been so much useless advice on this thread."` - Please don't be putting things like this in your answers, it is just being rude if you disagree with an answer then downvote it and leave a comment explaining the downvote -1 for the bad comment in your answer which I have removed and the fact it doesn't help.

Answer (score -2):

Diclare inAppManager object outside the method. and use the following code

```
static IAPManager *inAppManager = nil;
+(id)getInstance
{

if (nil != inAppManager) {
        return inAppManager;
    }

  static dispatch_once_t pred;
  dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
    inAppManager = [[IAPManager alloc] init];
  });
  return inAppManager;
}
```

That may help you.

Thanks

Satya

Comment: Some how there is iAPManager instance, so it satisfies the first if EXC_BAD_ACCESS occurs

Comment: This is called an anti-pattern. Please read up on how static variables work, and how dispatch_once works.

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
+(instancetype)getInstance
{
  static id inAppManager;
  static dispatch_once_t pred;
  dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
    inAppManager = [[[self class] alloc] init];
  });
  return inAppManager;
}
```

Comment: i did it but still didnt work. though it called once if it goes inside block it should get an instance right.. the thing is .. that doesnt happen

Comment: are you stepping in your code while debugging and follow the code execution and it gets stuck?

Comment: its a block.. you cant follow the execution. once I call for the get instance it doesnt go in to the next line in the calling class

Comment: that's right. you're gonna have to write a test code to check on this method. but believe me, I've used and seen this pattern a lot and I'm sue there is nothing wrong with it. But that I can't say for your `init` method.

Comment: Yes I have also used this pattern for singletons. There is no init method in the class since its a custom. @M. Porooshani

Comment: So, it might be a problem in its `super`s `init`, but then again, it might be the **NSObject** itself. try adding a NSLog inside the block, something like `if(!inAppManager) { NSLog(@"Something's Wrong");}`...

Comment: Still Having the issue :(

Comment: I don't get it @Ashan! did you add the checking log inside your block? how did it go? is it nil in the block or not?

Comment: It doesn't even hit the first line of the getinstance method. Application just hangs. I have edited my question on how I call the iAPManager. Is there something to do with threads by any chance

Comment: @M.Porooshani: A `static` variable is initialized only once, and is by default initialized to zero. Therefore it does not make any difference if you write `static IAPManager *inAppManager = nil;` or `static IAPManager *inAppManager;` .

Comment: @Ashan Please change your code this way: change your method signature to: `+(instancetype)getInstance` and `static id inAppManager;` and `inAppManager=[[[self class] alloc] init];`

Comment: @Ashan I have edited my answer to reflect the changes needed to be done.

Comment: "It's a block. You can't follow the execution". Of course you can. You set a breakpoint on the first line of the block and go. It stops right there, and then you follow the execution of the code.